# Android:How To set set deafult value of Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I am creating a Dropdown(spinner) in which all days have to shown,but i want to set different Default value.Presently default and first value of spinner are same..Please help me how to do this...Code snippets are appreciated....
My is =>

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    spinner =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.days, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
   spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    TextView tv =(TextView)arg1;
    Toast.makeText(this, "YOu have selected"+tv.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

simple_spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

String.xml

'

```
<string name="app_name">Spinner</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string-array name="days">
    <item>Choose A day</item>
    <item>Sunday</item>
    <item>Monday</item>
    <item>Tuesday</item>
    <item>Wednesday</item>
    <item>Thrusday</item>
    <item>Friday</item>
    <item>Saturday</item>
</string-array>
```

'

Comment: what value want to set as default value in Spinner?

Comment: Choose a Day   or something like that....

Comment: Add "Choose a Day" in `R.array.days` ? have you tried this way?

Comment: Yes! i have tried but The Default value is repeated....as first value....Means Default value is same as first drop down element value..

Comment: please show `days.xml`

Comment: not setting your problem please explain more what you are getting when using "Choose a Day" in R.array.days if possible then use screen-shot in question for pointing what currently getting and what actually   you want

Comment: After adding choose a days to xml...The default value is set to "Choose a day" but the first element of dropdown(after default value) is also having value(choose a day) i am getting "Choose a day" twice.....(in default as well as first element)...i dont want this repeation...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71028/discussion-between-anurag-goel-and--k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your `R.array.days` with the *hint* as the last element.

```
<string-array name="days">
  <item>Sunday</item>
  <item>Monday</item>
  <item>Tuesday</item>
  <item>Wednesday</item>
  <item>Thursday</item>
  <item>Friday</item>
  <item>Saturday</item>
  <item>Choose a Day</item> <!-- Hint -->
</string-array>
```

Now, instantiate and set your `ArrayAdapter` as

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
String[] dayValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dayValues) {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
         int c = super.getCount();
         if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() < c - 1) return c;
         return c > 0 ? c - 1 : c;
    }
};
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Finally, set your *hint* as the default spinner value

```
spinner.setSelection(dayValues.length - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks but is it only Works for first..time .when i select an option then default value disappears...

Comment: Before the for loop of arraylist just append the string that what you want to display as first item in the adapter .

Answer (score 1):

You can to it by using the function : **setSelection(Integer)**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    spinner =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.days, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinner.setSelection(positionSpinner);
}
```

**EDIT :**
The only solution I think is to create your own spinner adapter and but the text as the last item and using the getCount in order to not display it.

```
class MySpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public MySpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount() - 1; // This makes not show the last item
    }

    @Override
    public SpinnerItem getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

}
```

Finally :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    spinner =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayList itemsSpinner = new ArrayList(); 
    itemsSpinner.add("Day 1"); 
    itemsSpinner.add("Day 2"); 
    itemsSpinner.add("Choose a day"); // Last item

    MySpinnerAdapter adapterSpinner = new MySpinnerAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, itemsSpinner );
    adapterSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);
    spinner.setSelection(items.size() - 1);
}
```

Comment: It will set default value as position what we pass int the method...but I want to set default value as "choose a day".....plz help

Comment: Aha, your edit seems to be inspired by my post a lot :)

Comment: lol, I edited it at the same times as you. We just think at the same solution by using a different approach ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a little component to get this. Just add a hint text in AutoCompleteTexview and build CompleteSpinner with it.

https://github.com/FernandoGaliay/CompleteSpinner